# How to use lineBreak inside the beforePageContent in jspdf autoTable

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

i'm using `overFlow : linebreak` in my program .And it work's fine this is my code ,

```js
styles: {
                    fillStyle: 'DF',
                       overflow: 'linebreak',
                       columnWidth: 110,
                       lineWidth: 2,
                       lineColor: [85, 51, 27]
                           
                     }
```

But that doesn't reflect inside the `beforePageContent` , Here is that code ,

```js
beforePageContent: function(data) {
                      doc.setFontSize(12);
                      doc.setFont("courier");
                      doc.text("Process Name :",20 ,15);
                      doc.setFontStyle('bold');
                      //doc.overflow('linebreak');
                         doc.setFontStyle('normal');
                       doc.text("Description :"+sampData, 20, 30);
                         
                         
                     },
```

So how can i use `lineBreak` inside my `beforePageContent` block .

Comment: @Simon Bengtsson , Help me out from this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `overflow: linebreak;` style is only for `jspdf-autotable`. In the hooks you are using pure jspdf and need to use jspdf methods. There are two functions that you are probably going to be helpful. The first one is `doc.getStringUnitWidth("hello")` and the second is `doc.splitTextToSize("A longer title that might be split", 50)`.

**Example 1:**

```
var strArr = doc.splitTextToSize("A longer title that might be split", 50)
doc.text(strArr, 50, 50);
```

**Example 2:**

```
var str = "A longer title that /n is split";
doc.text(str, 50, 50);
```

Comment: ,Can you Put the link for this Above example so that i can get some more clarification .

Comment: Added two examples now, I quickly googled and couldn't find any references to the above functions. You either test it though or check the jspdf source code.